# Find sku, avg margin and join with another table

Tags: mysql

I want to join following 2 tables. BUt it's showing unknown column in unspsc_tble.entity_id. But when I run prdct_tbl or only unspsc_tbl code alone it runs and gives me answer. I'm confused what's I'mdoing wrong while joining these 2 tbl? Can anyone help?

```
SELECT prdct_tbl.sku, prdct_tbl.avg_margin, unspsc_tbl.unspsc 
FROM 
(SELECT e.sku, e.entity_id, (eav.value * 0.2) AS 'avg_margin' 
FROM catalog_product_entity e 
JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal eav 
  ON e.entity_id = eav.entity_id 
JOIN eav_attribute ea 
  ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id 
WHERE ea.attribute_code = 'price') AS prdct_tbl 
JOIN 
(SELECT eav.value AS 'unspsc', e.sku, e.entity_id 
FROM catalog_product_entity e 
JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar eav 
  ON e.entity_id = eav.entity_id 
JOIN eav_attribute ea 
  ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id 
WHERE ea.attribute_code = 'unspsccode') AS unspsc_tbl 
 ON unspsc_tbl.entity.id = prdct_tbl.entity.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT prdct_tbl.sku, prdct_tbl.avg_margin, unspsc_tbl.unspsc 
FROM 
(SELECT e.sku, e.entity_id, (eav.value * 0.2) AS 'avg_margin' 
FROM catalog_product_entity e 
JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal eav 
  ON e.entity_id = eav.entity_id 
JOIN eav_attribute ea 
  ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id 
WHERE ea.attribute_code = 'price') AS prdct_tbl 
JOIN 
(SELECT eav.value AS 'unspsc', e.sku, e.entity_id 
FROM catalog_product_entity e 
JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar eav 
  ON e.entity_id = eav.entity_id 
JOIN eav_attribute ea 
  ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id 
WHERE ea.attribute_code = 'unspsccode') AS unspsc_tbl 
 ON unspsc_tbl.entity_id = prdct_tbl.entity_id
```

Try this.

Comment: Oh Thanks. I was so stupid that instead of _ I was putting . in entity id. That means my code was right. Thanks for your help.